# How to write regex to extract a value from json response and pass it to next test in jmeter

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I am using Jmeter 2.13 version to write some API tests. 
I am running a login test first. I want to extra a value from "sessionToken" from the json response from the login test and pass it to my next test.

Here is how my json looks like:

```
{
 "values": [
  {
   "lastModifiedTimestamp": "1447435096377",
   "lastModifiedUserId": "1",
   "name": "blah blah",
   "group": "newgroup",
   "systemUserId": "5194842789380096",
   "givenName": "test",
   "familyName": "testnew",
   "sessionToken": "8d49aec3-1f09-48eb-a946-543a6f2d9950",
 }
```

Here is the regex I am using in my "Regular Expression Extractor"
$.values.sessionToken

But, it never works. Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Don't use regex!!! Parse the JSON and extract the value!!!

Comment: If you know your data's format, you should parse it and extract the value directly.  This applies to JSON, XML, HTML, delimited records, etc.  Relying on regex to do it for you may be a quick fix, but it's **very** prone to breaking or giving incorrect results.

Comment: I tried the JSON Path Extractor as well. Using this JSONPath Expression $.values[*].sessionToken

Comment: Wrote the above JSON Path Extractor for my login test. Passed the name as sessionToken and value as ${SESSIONTOKEN} (this is the variable I created in JSON Path Extractor)

Comment: Do i need to write some BSF Postprocessor script here?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: any variable name, i.e. `sessionToken`
- Regular Expression: `"sessionToken": "(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

  [image: Regular Expression Extractor]

Refer the extracted value as `${sessionToken}` where required.

Reference material:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter's [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642)

Answer (score 0):

As the response is JSON, you can use **JSON Path Extractor** check this link -

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/

you need to use `$.values[0].sessionToken` in the json path

You can also use Regular Expression Extractor with this expression `"sessionToken": "(.*?)"`. The only advantage is it is faster than JSON path extractor.

Comment: Thanks @Vinoth. Since the sessionToken is in the first level, I presume you gave in the parent node values[0]. But, what if it the nth element. Can I use it as  $.values[*].sessionToken